# Why ESP8266 module can connect to my iPhone Hotspot but cannot connection to my home wifi?

Tags: arduino, wifi, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

Here is the code for scanning WiFi network and connecting to the WiFi.

```
#include<ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include<Arduino.h>
#define USER_SERIAL Serial 
const char* ssid = "*****";
const char* pass = "*****";

void setup() {
  USER_SERIAL.begin(115200);
  searchWifi();
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.hostname("ESP-host");
  WiFi.setPhyMode(WIFI_PHY_MODE_11G);
  WiFi.enableInsecureWEP(true);
  WiFi.begin(ssid,pass);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    USER_SERIAL.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }
  USER_SERIAL.print("");
  USER_SERIAL.println("WiFi connected");
  USER_SERIAL.print("IP Address: ");
  USER_SERIAL.println(WiFi.localIP());
  WiFi.setAutoReconnect(true);
  WiFi.persistent(true);
  
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

 void searchWifi(){
  int numberOfNetwork = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  USER_SERIAL.println("-----");
  for ( int i = 0; i< numberOfNetwork;i++){
    USER_SERIAL.print("Network name: ");
    USER_SERIAL.println(WiFi.SSID(i));
    USER_SERIAL.print("Signal Strength: ");
    USER_SERIAL.println(WiFi.RSSI(i));
    USER_SERIAL.println("-------------");
  }
}
```

My WiFi is in 11bgn mixed mode, so it means that my connection allow all device to be connected. Moreover, my WiFi router is also have 2,4gHz frequency which is the requirement for ESP8266 to allow connection.

Comment: Could you not try the regular procedure for connecting the esp8266 to the WIFI?

Comment: The code works both for my WIFI and hotspot.